# How can I find the Weierstrass form of an elliptic curve given as a singular quartic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Suppose you have an elliptic curve given as a singular quartic and you want to find the Weierstrass form of this elliptic curve. In particular you know that the singular points of this quartic are exactly the points at infinity of the x-axis and the y-axis and they are both double points. 
Does anyone know a method to find the Weierstrass form of this curve?